# Does Stack Exchange have an Economics section?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, site-recommendation

I was wondering if there is a viable place on Stack Exchange to ask economics-related questions.  Questions I'd have in particular could be equation-based or theoretical.  I suppose the equation-based questions could possibly fit into mathematics but I haven't checked their FAQ.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any Stack Exchange site for economics questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212853/is-there-any-stack-exchange-site-for-economics-questions)

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden are you creating an infinite loop?

Comment: In a sense, yes, I guess, sorry about that. I was not sure how to flag the three post which look like duplicate to me. I guess marking two of them as duplicate of the post I thought was best would have been the way to go?

Comment: @MartinVanderLinden I'm just messing with you. It seems valid, although mine is older, they seem to have significant answers on both

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update: [Economics is back!](https://economics.stackexchange.com/). For pure economic theory and its implication, that is the site to go to.

That said, there are other sites to consider, as my previous answer showed.

---

While Economics Stack Exchange is, alas, no more, there is some overlap with existing proposals.

- **[Politics](http://politics.stackexchange.com)**

  has a certain amount of scope for macroeconomic issues.  Because Politics deals with policy questions as being on-topic, we often use economic theory to explain policy choices.  Understanding the exact nature of key macroeconomic players (Federal Reserve / Central Bank for monetary policy, Legislatures around the world for fiscal policy) is also on topic.  What is excluded is pure economic theory for its own sake.

  [How can a currency be manipulated?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/how-can-a-currency-be-manipulated)

  [How do prison phone monopolies get around the Sherman Anti-Trust Act?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/how-do-prison-phone-monopolies-get-around-the-sherman-anti-trust-act)

  [How much of the deficit would be reduced by increasing taxes on the top 1% to 1990s levels?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1149/how-much-of-the-deficit-would-be-reduced-by-increasing-taxes-on-the-top-1-to-19)

NOTE: Politics is [particularly friendly towards macroeconomic questions](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1466/23)

- **[Personal Finance and Money](http://money.stackexhange.com)**

  tolerates what I would call concrete Microeconomics.  While legal issues and pure economic theory are off-topic, there is some scope for understanding the incentives that drive individual financial decisions. Time Value of Money / Present Value, Tax incentives, and the like seem to fit. While personal choice and rational actor theory is typically well received, pure economic theory is usually not.

  [Are there any investment strategies which take advantage of an in-the-money option price that incorporates no "time value"?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24616/are-there-any-investment-strategies-which-take-advantage-of-an-in-the-money-opti)

  [Margin account: how to calculate the stock price that might trigger a liquidation of positions?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/24566/margin-account-how-to-calculate-the-stock-price-that-might-trigger-a-liquidatio)

  [How to evaluate different account (RRSP, TFSA, ...) and investment types (equities, bonds, cash) combinations](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21154/how-to-evaluate-different-account-rrsp-tfsa-and-investment-types-equiti)
- [Quantitative](http://quant.stackexchange.com) is more geared to finance, but a lot of economic theory goes there too...
- **[History](http://history.stackexchange.com)**

  often has scope for historical economic data questions.

  [How much of an impact did the Roman emperors' civil wars have on their decision to debase the coinage?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/8847/how-much-of-an-impact-did-the-roman-emperors-civil-wars-have-on-their-decision)

  [Does History confirm that prosperity, capitalism, and some form "democracy" or representative republican form of government always go hand in hand?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10237/does-history-confirm-that-prosperity-capitalism-and-some-form-democracy-or-r)

  [How rich were carpenters in the Roman province of Iudaea in the 1st century AD?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/how-rich-were-carpenters-in-the-roman-province-of-iudaea-in-the-1st-century-ad)
- **[Mathematics](http://math.stackexchange.com)**

  discusses the logical implications of logic topics like game theory.

  [Total differential Economics Application](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511896/total-differential-economics-application)

  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499417/ricardian-model-under-free-trade

  [what is a connection between two simple yet important economics and math formula: elasticity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499139/what-is-a-connection-between-two-simple-yet-important-economics-and-math-formula)

Beyond that, as stated, Area 51 occasionally has Social Sciences and economic SE proposals, but the critical mass rarely seems to gather to tip them over the edge.

Comment: [quant.se] too.

Answer (score 11):

Unfortunately, Economics Stack Exchange didn't have enough activity during its beta phase and it [was closed](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/). You can download the data dump of all its questions from its [Area51 proposal page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics).

There seem to be two new related proposals, [Economics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42351/economics) and [Finance & Economics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41407/finance-economics) that may be worth following. From the current sites, [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) and [Personal Finance and Money](https://money.stackexchange.com/) may be close to what you are looking for, depending on what your actual question is, but please make sure to read their FAQs and search for similar questions before asking.

Comment: shoot, is there a suitable place related questions could be asked?

Answer (score 2):

There is now a new Economics.SE beta which you can access at https://economics.stackexchange.com/.