# All sites should be available when requesting closure with migration

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

I believe all sites should be available in the closure UI.

Then when a site is not actually available for automatic migration, other options should appear.

What appears will depend upon the site and/or why the site is not available for automatic migration.

(This question was added using the mobile site, and so without the benefit of suggested existing questions, or a preview.)

I originally thought this when a code-golf-like question was posted on Stack Overflow itself, and, accessing the site from a mobile, I wanted to quickly suggest that's where it should go. The current UI leaves you with a list of available migration sites and no further possibilities. You have to start over and try to choose the 'correct' option.

Comment: Since a lot of garbadge was migrated in the past the available sites changed. Offering **all** sites would be counter productive.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate of ["Off topic questions and redirect to affiliated sites"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77264/off-topic-questions-and-redirect-to-affiliated-sites), but while that was positively received when it was asked nearly three years ago, we've had some bad experiences with migrations since. Contrast that with the answers in ["What is the reasoning behind restricting the number of migration paths?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203318/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-restricting-the-number-of-migration-paths)

Comment: @juergen I'm not suggesting all sites be available for migration, just the illusion of that, then offer something that is allowed.

Comment: But that would lead to bad migrations too, wouldn't it? If I click Server Fault and I'm not allowed to choose it, I'll choose whatever it gives me as an alternative. Even though the question would be perfect for Server Fault.

Comment: @Pëkka "offer something that is allowed" should then include the manual request for migration.

Comment: @Mark that's a fair point. Having that as a 6th option in the migration menu might make sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps not *all* sites should be included, but I think the off-topic flagging box could use some improvement along the lines of your question.

Currently, the flagging box is organized rather poorly:
[image: sad]

At the very least, the "question improvement"-related flags should be grouped together, as should the "migration" flags. Combining that idea with the question at hand (and some content stolen from the new StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™), you get something like this:
[image: happy!]

Where the green-arrowed content is optional text for clarification. If that's not necessary, [here's the clean version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdzCM.png).

Comment: You do realize that the Super User and Server Fault items *do not migrate* a post?

Comment: @slhck I thought after enough of those flags (or if a mod catches one) it will be migrated. What exactly *do* they do? In any case, the order I suggested creates two groups of choices: [edit to make on-topic for SO], and [should be asked elsewhere].

Comment: They're just like regular off topic reasons. The question will be closed as off topic with the selected text. If you want the question migrated you need to click *it belongs on another site…* (To me the SU and SF options don't make sense at all, because if the question was too bad to be migrated, we shouldn't point the OP to another site, and if it was good enough, then it should be migrated anyway. )

Comment: @slhck My mistake. The question I used for my examples didn't have that option (possibly because it already had answers; what causes that option to no longer be offered?). You make a good point.

Comment: Sure, no worries. Questions older than 60 days cannot be migrated—I assume that was the case for your example.

Comment: @slhck I realize now that I missed the point of this question, and my answer is actually pretty off-topic. The migration UI in question is not even the same menu. However, I find my answer good enough to be a standalone feature request, and combining it with your argument, that feature request ought to be an overhaul of the flagging UI. I'll ping you when I get that question written.