# Is there a place to get the textual overview (what is on-topic) of all sites?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, scope, stackexchange.com

Between:

- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)
- [Does Stack Exchange have an Economics section?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141410/does-stackexchange-have-an-economics-section)
- and other random guidance I've found by perusing the "on-topic / off-topic" sections of help pages,

there seems to be a need to help disambiguate sites.  While the current [sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) is pretty, it doesn't really do a good job of directing would-be users to the appropriate sites for their questions.  Likewise, this [Map of all Stack Exchange sites (except the three biggest)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157976/map-of-all-se-sites-except-the-3-biggest) is interesting, but not really the answer either.

Somewhere, there should be some sort of listing that summarizes the on-topic locus of each site, and it could be as simple as a list of the sites, along with their short descriptions next to them.

Ideally, there would even be a simple little search function that would allow a user to search through all of the site descriptions as well.

Simply put, guidance around the appropriate site seems in order, and it would be nice to capture it in a straightforward fashion.

Comment: @AmalMurali That is for **one** site. This question is about gathering a summary of what **all** sites are about.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Yeah, got it. +1 to the question.

Comment: [This](http://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list) or more specific?

Comment: @Dukeling That is a very good start.  It would be nice if instead of showing the traffic, we could have a page like that showing the 'off-topic'.  As it stands, though, again, a user wondering "so what does each of these sites do?" probably isn't going to imagine that the traffic page is the answer.

Comment: This is a cool idea.  I think it would be neat if it took the form of a taxonomy of subject areas.  Perhaps something like this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Contents/Portals.

Comment: A list of all sites with their `domain.com/help/on-topic` would do it, am I right?

Comment: @RobertSiemer Yup!

Comment: Adapt the userscript from this [Glorfindel's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/386788/289691)