# Is there any Stack Exchange site for economics questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I am an undergrad in economics and really want to get a helping hand as I get from math and stats from a Stack Exchange site for economics. Where can I post my questions on economics topics?

Comment: Questions more towards the micro- end of the spectrum might be on topic on [money.se], but have a look around, read their faq, and judge for yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently there none launched or in beta. There was once one http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1618/economics but it ended up closed in beta testing.

There is currently a proposal for another Economics site. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/61732/economics. Hopefully it will have much activity than the previous and get launched.

Comment: Thank you. If I don't get answers at the links given by you, can I ask it on [Finance](http://quant.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @honso You might not get answers from those link because they are not created sites yet. If your question is on topic for finance then ask it there

Answer (score 2):

There is currently a beta which you can access at https://economics.stackexchange.com/.